# support to login with javascript or

Tags: javascript, html

I am developing a web application using Facelets and Entity-Controller-EJB structure. In the application, there are contents which are reachable only if you are logged. A bean checks the login state every time you click on a button/link for the restricted contents, and redirects you either to the selected page or to the login page.

I thought that this way is not safe, as you can write the link directly in the browser instead of generating it from a button that checks the bean. So what should I do? Is there a render option embeddable in each page or should I write a javascript function? In this case, what should I do? I have studied js fundamentals but don't really know how to implement this control!
Thank you for reading!

Comment: What you **should** do is press "enter" key every once in a while when you type

Answer (score 0):

#### You cannot rely only on frontend to deny access to some parts of a web application.

This because all the HTML/CSS/Javascript is downloaded on users' browser, so they can read your code and your authentication mechanism, and understand how to bypass it (or just disable it).

More on this: [Why are browsers allowed to display client-side source code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5348809/why-are-browsers-allowed-to-display-client-side-source-code)

What you need is implementing some security mechanism in the backed.

The simplest one is to delegate this to your webserver ([here](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/auth.html) the instructions for Apache) and then use something similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/491914/pure-javascript-code-for-http-basic-authentication#492004) to do login.

Another way is to have a proper backend: you send data to it (email/password) and it provides you a token that you use to access protected resources.

Or also, dinamically create your documents on server side, only if the user is authenticated.

Comment: Well, I know that mine was a simple way to login. So, having a form where you write user and pass (values stored in a bean), and then activating the "Login" button that tries to pull from the database an user with the same name (if exists) and then match password, is it totally unsafe? Why?